# Easiest way to get json and parse it using JQuery and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to get this code snipped to work but I can't seem to figure this out. The goal is to return and parse a json object in the most simple, easiest way possible. Here is the code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
  $.getJSON('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:TSLA', function(data) {
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.id;
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

UPDATE:

I was able to figure it out with all of the assistance down below, Thank you! I will post the solution for future cases. The problem was that I had forgotten about the callback since I wasn't following Same Origin Policy.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.getJSON('https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NASDAQ:TSLA&callback=?', function(data) {
     $('#demo').text(data[0].id);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no need to use `JSON.parse` in `$.getJSON`. Data returned to callback will already be parsed to array/object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` object is an `array` so you have to access an element using `indexes`.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj[0].id;
```

Also, you do not need `JSON.parse` method because `data` returned to callback is already a `json` object.

Comment: Making the change you recommended did not solve this though. Am I doing something wrong? Is there something I need to change

Comment: You do not need `json.parse` method, because `data` is already a `json`.

Comment: So I got rid of the json.parse method and just assigned data to obj but still no luck here.

<script>
  $.getJSON('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:TSLA', function(data) {
   var obj = data;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj[0].id;
  });
</script>

Comment: Statements about json are inaccurate .... json is string by definition, data returned to callback is object

Answer (score 1):

your code in your question is likely to be the shortest way to parse `JSON` data expected from the request.. that shortcut comes from:

```
var http = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:TSLA',
    dataType: "json"        //This is what makes jQuery parse the data in the expected format
});

http.done(function(data){
    // data is already parsed as JSON
    $("#demo").text(data.id);
});
```

**EDIT:** Just now i checked the response of your request and it turns out it is a commented `JSON Array` and so this will make the parse to fail.

In order to actually parse the commented `JSON` response, the content has to remove the initial chars which makes the content to be commented, after that, the response can finally be parsed and extract the desired data

```
// the respone will come as string format and jQuery ajax will try to guess what's the dataType from
// the response, just to be sure i will ask Ajax to get the data as String (this is not necessary)
var http = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:TSLA',
    dataType: "string"
});

http.done(function(data){
    // slice the first 3 chars which makes the JSON to be commented
    var json = data.slice(3);

    // now this JSON is finally a valid JSON, so it can be parsed
    data = JSON.parse(json);

    // the data is now an Array of 1 element, we can now extract and print the data this way
    if(data.length == 1){
        $("#demo").text(data[0].id);

        // to print data using native Javascript
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = data[0].id;
    }

    // in case the Array has more than 1 element and yet you want to print all of them,
    // you can iterate the Array
    for(i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
        var d = data[i];

        // do something the the iterated data
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation but how do I get it to print correctly?

Comment: I have edited the answer to show you how you could use it in the `DOM`

Comment: i just checked the the response of your desired request, turns out the response is a `JSON Array` of objects, which comes commented, so the parse from either `jQuery` or `JSON.parse()` will fail cause the content is not actually a `JSON` type response

Comment: So how do I get this to work with the OP code snippet?

Comment: i will update the answer soon so you could see how it can be parsed and printed in the `DOM`

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I supplemented your provide code in the original snippet, but to no avail. It also seems that this may not be the most simplistic way to solve this.

Comment: it's alright, the other way would be to split the code in functions, but other than that.. i cannot figure out a simpler way to parse the response just because the response is a commented `JSON`

Comment: How do I use document.getlElementById with this?

Comment: i just edited the answer to show you how to print data using native `JavaScript` code

Comment: I tried putting this as the <script> in the original example and can't get it to work still. It seems correct but for some reason it will not work for me.

Comment: it does not work because probably the jQuery code is being executed before jQuery is ready, probably the fix would be to wrap the whole code in `$(document).ready();`

Comment: It seems this doesn't work because of same origin policy