# Read & parse JSON response from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have an API endpoint like this:
https://client.systemonesoftware.com/bannink/json/?language=nl

I need to read and parse it into a table with all the information. But I get no output when I try to do it with Javascript.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('https://client.systemonesoftware.com/bannink/json/?language=nl', function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);

        alert(json.cached);
        alert(json.data[1].id);
    });
    </script>
```

This piece of code gives nothing..

Comment: Read [the documentation for `getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: You can run your code in Chrome Developer Tools with json to see the structure of the data when it hits a breakpoint.

Comment: I added the jQuery tag, you are using JavaScript but more specifically you are using jQuery XHR (ajax): https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, which already deserializes the response as JSON. As others mentioned, it is best to inspect the response in the browser and not guess about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to get json and parse it using JQuery and Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181245/easiest-way-to-get-json-and-parse-it-using-jquery-and-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

[$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) returns JavaScript object so you don't need to parse it, try:

```js
$.getJSON('https://client.systemonesoftware.com/bannink/json/?language=nl', function(json) {
        console.log(json.data[1].id);            
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of the response.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that the data already comes through parsed:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://client.systemonesoftware.com/bannink/json/?language=nl', function(json) {
    alert(json.cached);
    alert(json.data[1].id);
});
</script>
```